# Autocomplete Jquery get id and name

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm new into all this and need some help getting the id and the name of a game from my database with autocomplete

Everything works except, I can't get the id.

I have a get_games.php which looks like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{        
    $results[$row['id']] =  $row['title'];
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

My Jquery

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#games" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'get_games.php',
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id" ).val( ui.item.id );
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Html

```
<input id="games" />
<input id="id" />
```

I see all the titles in the games input but no id.

Comment: when is use ui.item.value i'm getting the "title"

Comment: label gives me the title too, is something wrong with my array?{"1":" game1","2":" game2","69":" game3"} looks like this after encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate object array with properties `value` (`id` value) and `label`(`title` value) and later get it using `ui.item.value`.

**PHP :**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{        
    $results[] =  array(
         'label' => $row['title'],
         'value' => $row['id'],
        );
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(function() {
   $( "#games" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'get_games.php',
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you :)

Comment: @SKSK : glad to help :)